# why discord.py gives error to convery message to a number

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

i need help in here, i dont know what's wrong with my code. Can someone explain?

```
@client.command()
async def gameONE(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome to the GAME! (between 1-20) ")

    pcNumber = random.randint(0,21)
    print(pcNumber)

    await ctx.send("Enter a number please.. ")
    userNumber = await client.wait_for("message")
    corro = float(userNumber.contect)
    if pcNumber > corro:
        ctx.send("PC won!")
    elif corro > pcNumber:
        ctx.send("YOU won!")
    else:
        ctx.send("I didnt understand")
```

**it gives me this error :**

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'contect'
```

Comment: Did you mean `Message.content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userNumber.contect` should instead be `userNumber.content`.

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: Put `await` before each of the `ctx.send()` commands.

Comment: If it was correct make sure to mark this answer as correct.